# How do we redirect all requests to one domain to a section of another domain?

Tags: jsp, url, redirect

We have two domains, `example.com` and `example.net`· We want every request to `example.net` to redirect to `example.com/example_section/index.jsp`. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Please give your need in more details.  If you simply redirect just do in js by onclick event. 
onclick = 'window.location.href="http://www.site.com/sectionxxx/index.jsp"' like that you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a .htaccess file on the server

```
Redirect permanent http://www.example.net/index.jsp http://www.example.com/example_section/index.jsp.
```

Or you can create page at `http://www.example.net/index.jsp` page and add

```
<% 
    String redirectURL = "http://www.example.com/example_section/index.jsp"; 
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

Or you can write on the same page

```
<jsp: forward page="http://www.example.com/example_section/index.jsp"/>
```

This will forward the page.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file will only work if your servletcontainer is fronted by Apache HTTPD (since `.htaccess` files are Apache HTTPD specific, won't work on Tomcat and so on). The scriptlet way will work, but a `Filter` like [this one](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) is the preferred way. The `jsp:forward` is entirely server-side and will not reflect the URL change in browser address bar.